# "Mobile Broadband Disabled" shown in the network connections menu - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mobile-broadband

The system shows *Mobile Broadband Disabled* in the network connections menu but the dongle is working with other laptops. Kindly help me figure out this issue.

[image: Network Connections]

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information here. Could you update your question to include: the type of dongle, the brand and model of your computer, what computers the dongle works with (their brand, model, and operating system). With some specific information, it is easier to provide specific suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Huawei 3372, Dell E7490... dongle will start to work if you fresh install the OS to the same machine.